# Can the Spring Framework be used for batch applications?

Tags: java, spring, command-line, frameworks, spring-batch

My company is switching to Spring for our Java framework, and from what I understand it will work well for that, but we also have many Java batch applications*.  Does Spring have adequate support for running batch applications?  What features of spring will be useful in this environment, and won't work at all?

* Java command line programs that run backend processes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [Spring project](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) for that.

Comment: Excellent.  This was exactly the sort of thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely yes. Spring can run in any environment.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this only applies to parts of Spring; e.g. the IoC framework.  Much of Spring only makes sense in a web container.

Comment: I don't think that's a fair characterization. Spring has lots of components in it, and yes of course the web and servlet components only make sense in a web container; but you can use the core or JDBC or test components anywhere.